# It is possible to pass an array from jquery to TWIG?

Tags: jquery, twig

I have an  array named `days` retrieved in jquery:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 4
            [name] => text_4
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 7
            [name] => text_7
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 10
            [name] => text_10
        )
)
```

And part of the TWIG template where i need to get `days`:

```
<ul id="days">
    {% for day in days %}
        {% if day.value == mean_day  %} 
            <li class="dropdown" > <a href="#" class="night-value selected-value"  value="{{ day.value }}" selected="selected">{{ day.name }}</a></li>
        {% else %} 
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"  class="night-value" value="{{ day.value }}">{{ day.name }}</a></li>   
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

It is possible to pass `days` to the TWIG template and refresh just only that ul `days` without reloading whole page?

Comment: How are you rendering the twig template?

Comment: this is Opencart templates http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. I'm assuming that because you linked to the standard php docs that the template is being rendered server-side, in which case you cannot get the template to re-render without re-requesting the page from the server. You would have to pass the parameters from jquery to a HTTP request and the server would have to parse the parameters and use them in the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. jQuery running on the client side, TWIG runs on the server side.
You can expose server side variables for the Frontend, but you can't do the inverse, because when the frontend runs, the backend was finished.

Normally you can send frontend data to the server, using Ajax, but this is not your case.

Anyway, if you have this information on the frontend side, probably you had it on the server side.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this data i have also in server side.  But how to refresh just only this `days` without reloading whole page?

Comment: I have solved my problem using jQuery autocomplete with callback ajax json....

Comment: Using ajax, you can make a server request, grab the data, and update some part of DOM, but not using TWIG anymore.

On the client side, there is no more TWIG.

Comment: Yes I understand that. So using ajax autocomplete UI i just retrieve updated data from the server without refreshing the page. This no difference TWIG, HTML, or something else.